# Trying to set color with alpha crashes

Tags: ios, core-graphics, exc-bad-access, alpha, uicolor

I'm trying to set the fill `UIColor` to have `alpha`

```
glassColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3].CGColor;
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, glassColor);
...
```

The second line crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Any ideas as to why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially your problem is that ARC is releasing the UIColor as it is not being used. You need to retain the CGColor structure. You can do it the following way.

```
 CGColorRef aColorRef = CGColorRetain([[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.82 alpha:1.0] CGColor] );
 CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, aColorRef);
```

And don't forget to release it once you are done using it:

```
 CGColorRelease(aColorRef);
```

Answer (score 3):

In ARC try to use

```
       UIColor *glasscolor = [UIColor colorWithRed: red 
                                   green: green 
                                    blue: blue 
                                   alpha: your alpha value];// 
       [view setBackgroundColor:glasscolor];
```

example for a very light gray

```
        UIColor *glasscolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.945 green:0.945 blue:0.945 alpha:1.0]
        [view setBackgroundColor:glasscolor];
```